# TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref.ReferenceType' object

Tags: python, apscheduler, aiogram, sqlite3-python

I've tried to shedule 2 jobs:

```
scheduler.add_job(send_delayed_message, 'date', run_date=datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=1), kwargs={'id': order['ID'], 'bot': bot}, id=f'{order["ID"]}_first')
scheduler.add_job(send_delayed_message, 'date', run_date=datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=3), kwargs={'id': order['ID'], 'bot': bot}, id=f'{order["ID"]}_second')
```

This is the func:

```
async def send_dealayed_message(id, bot):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=id, text='Seems you didn"t come to us so far, so it"s time to do it!')
```

This is entire scheduler code:

```
scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(timezone='Europe/Moscow')
scheduler.add_jobstore(SQLAlchemyJobStore(url='sqlite:///ProjectDB.sqlite'))
```

The scheduler starts when the telegram bot starts, and DB creates before the scheduler starts

This is the full error code:

```
But i get this:
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-47' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=TypeError("cannot pickle '_asyncio.Task' object")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\projects\TelegramBot\main.py", line 199, in get_confirm
    await create_order(order, bot=bot)
  File "c:\Users\user\projects\TelegramBot\DataBase.py", line 97, in create_order
    scheduler.add_job(send_dealayed_message, 'date', run_date=datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=1), kwargs={'id': order['ID'], 'bot': bot}, id=f'{order["ID"]}_first')
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\apscheduler\schedulers\base.py", line 447, in add_job
    self._real_add_job(job, jobstore, replace_existing)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\apscheduler\schedulers\base.py", line 871, in _real_add_job
    store.add_job(job)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\apscheduler\jobstores\sqlalchemy.py", line 97, in add_job
    'job_state': pickle.dumps(job.__getstate__(), self.pickle_protocol)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: cannot pickle '_asyncio.Task' object
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. And here is my final solution.

```
from asyncio.coroutines import _is_coroutine
from typing import Optional

from aiogram import Bot
from aiogram.methods import TelegramMethod

class TelegramMethodJob:
    _is_coroutine = _is_coroutine
    _bot = None

    def __init__(self, method: TelegramMethod):
        self.method = method
        self.method._bot = None

    async def call(self):
        self.method._bot = TelegramMethodJob._bot
        return await self.method

    @classmethod
    def set_bot(cls, bot: Optional[Bot]):
        cls._bot = bot
```

Clear the `_bot` member and set it again when called.

usage:

```
bot = Bot(...)
TelegramMethodJob.set_bot(bot)
scheduler = MyScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(TelegramMethodJob(bot.send_message(...)))
```